# Altair for interactive plot of connections among airports (time series)

Tags: python, charts, altair

I'm new to altair and I'm trying to adapt this plot from the altair gallery [Connections Among U.S. Airports Interactive](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/airport_connections.html) to be a time series.

The dataframe is the following, where each Airport is identified by its ICAO code. The idea is to have an interactive slider to move between the years while the bubble size changes with the values of the "**size**" variable instead of the number of connections between the different airports.

```
        icao        size    longitude   latitude    year
0       RKPC        1.00    126.49      33.51       2017
1       RKSS        0.88    126.79      37.55       2017
2       ZGSZ        0.43    113.81      22.63       2017
3       RJTT        0.43    139.77      35.55       2017
4       VHHH        0.38    113.91      22.30       2017
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2486    YBLA        0.76    146.00     -36.55       2018
2487    YCOM        0.52    148.97     -36.30       2018
2488    YPCC        0.22    96.83      -12.18       2018
2489    YWGT        0.12    146.30     -36.41       2018
2490    ZBNY        0.03    116.38      39.78       2018
```

The following code is from the example cited before.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

# Since these data are each more than 5,000 rows we'll import from the URLs
airports = data.airports.url
flights_airport = data.flights_airport.url

states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature="states")

# Create mouseover selection
select_city = alt.selection_single(
    on="mouseover", nearest=True, fields=["origin"], empty="none"
)

# Define which attributes to lookup from airports.csv
lookup_data = alt.LookupData(
    airports, key="iata", fields=["state", "latitude", "longitude"]
)

background = alt.Chart(states).mark_geoshape(
    fill="lightgray",
    stroke="white"
).properties(
    width=750,
    height=500
).project("albersUsa")

connections = alt.Chart(flights_airport).mark_rule(opacity=0.35).encode(
    latitude="latitude:Q",
    longitude="longitude:Q",
    latitude2="lat2:Q",
    longitude2="lon2:Q"
).transform_lookup(
    lookup="origin",
    from_=lookup_data
).transform_lookup(
    lookup="destination",
    from_=lookup_data,
    as_=["state", "lat2", "lon2"]
).transform_filter(
    select_city
)

points = alt.Chart(flights_airport).mark_circle().encode(
    latitude="latitude:Q",
    longitude="longitude:Q",
    size=alt.Size("routes:Q", scale=alt.Scale(range=[0, 1000]), legend=None),
    order=alt.Order("routes:Q", sort="descending"),
    tooltip=["origin:N", "routes:Q"]
).transform_aggregate(
    routes="count()",
    groupby=["origin"]
).transform_lookup(
    lookup="origin",
    from_=lookup_data
).transform_filter(
    (alt.datum.state != "PR") & (alt.datum.state != "VI")
).add_selection(
    select_city
)

(background + connections + points).configure_view(stroke=None)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you want the scatter chart to do in response to the slider, and since you did not provide complete code I can't run your example to see what you're seeing. Please provide more information about what you expect to see, as well as a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've already done. Without that, I doubt you'll get any helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I posted working examples to describe my problem.

Comment: Any ideas to how to combine both examples into one?

Comment: You've still not made clear what you want to do: How should the bubble size change in response to the slider? The bubble size reflects the number of airline routes per city, which has no dependence on year in the given dataset.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have yearly data for both, States and Airports. A time series with 2 dependent parameters (color and bubble size). I'm using another dataset with number of routes per year. The slider allows you to move in the time series.

Comment: The data in your example above is not a time series. This makes it difficult to answer your question, because the answer requires a dataset which is a time series.

Comment: I changed the question with the time series for the airports and simplified the question so it only focuses on the airport part (no choropleth).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [Filter Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/filter.html), following the example at [US Population Over Time](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_over_time.html). Here's what it might look like for your data:

```python
slider = alt.binding_range(min=2017, max=2018, step=1)
select_year = alt.selection_single(name="year", fields=['year'],
                                   bind=slider, init={'year': 2017})

points = alt.Chart(data).mark_circle().encode(
    latitude="latitude:Q",
    longitude="longitude:Q",
    size='size:Q'
).transform_filter(
    select_year
).add_selection(
    select_year
)
```